# Division in double precision

Tags: division, numerical-methods

I have two double variables:

```
a > 0
b >= 0
```

which could be tiny numbers. 'a' represents singular values of a matrix and 'b' represents the [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) constant. As part of the Tikhonov least squares solution, it is necessary to compute the quantity:

```
c = a*a / (a*a + b)
```

However if a is really small (ie small singular values of the matrix), `a*a` may not be representable in double precision. How can I compute this quotient c in a numerically stable way for the given ranges of a,b?

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is:

```
c = 1 / (1 + b / a / a)
```

To derive this equivalency, note that 1/*c* is (*a*^2 + *b*)/*c* and then decompose the fraction. This form might be more numerically stable since it doesn't require *a^2* to be calculated at any point. It'll still lose precision if both *b* and *a* are very small. If that case must be handled too, you might look at a Taylor series expansion (may or may not work for this case).